# I call data by ajax but it doesn't show on mobile device but works perfect on computer browser

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Ok, honestly the last couple hours I browsed through here and tried to find a solution that works for me. I tried different ones but as a matter of fact: nothing seems to work.

On the computer it works perfect. As soon as I call it on mobile: blank screen. I don't know anymore where to look. Googled and searched here so I know there are lots of topic with this but I tried to adjust their solutions to my script and it doesn't work. Can someone give me a push in the right direction?

Here is the html for it:

```
 <div runat="server" align="center">
    <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"  >
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><font face="Verdana" size="3" color="#FF0000" ><b><p><span class="blinking" id="Container1"></span></p></b></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="middle">
                <p align="center" runat="server" id="Container2"></p>
                </td>
            <td valign="middle">
                <div>
                    <span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 20px;">
                    <b> <p id="Container3"></p></b>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </div>`
```

So, the part above is relying on the following script:

```
var delay = 30000;

function loop() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "Sample.php",
       cache: false,
       async:false,
       success: function (data) {
          $("#Container1").html(data);
       }
    });
}

setInterval(loop, delay);
```

Like I said: the data gets fetched from the PHP and that works perfect as it shows on a computer. But it shows absolutely nothing on mobile devices!

Comment: try removing the deprecated `<font>` element for a start - also, the `blinking` class looks suspicious - what CSS do you have?

Comment: also, get rid of `async:false` you don't want synchronous `XMLHttpRequest`s - EVER

Comment: @JaromandaX ok, I removed the <font> element, no effect. Here is the CSS for the blinking class:
     `.blinking {

            animation: opacity 2s ease-in-out infinite;
            opacity: 1;
        }

        @keyframes opacity {
            0% {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        50% {
            opacity: 0
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        }`

Comment: don't put long pieces of code in a comment where it is unreadable - though, that seems to be in order - try removing `async:false`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yeah, sorry I thought it's formatted. I am new to this platform and learn how to use it. I will be better soon once I'm more familiar with it,

I removed async. No effect. It's literally the first time. Anything else I coded in HTML with either <div> or <p> or <span> was shown on all devices. Just this one refuses.

Comment: Does it also fail if you use device emulation mode in your desktop browser? Which mobile browser?

Comment: @JaromandaX Chrome on my phone and my tablet, Samsung browser on phone as well.  Edge on tablet. Non of them shows. Honestly : I didn't even know the browser can emulate... lol. sorry and I thought I know it all.. How embarrassing.

Comment: in the `success` function can you try to console log `$("#Container1")` and `data`  to see if they have the right data on mobile?

Comment: @tam.dangc In the dev tools I changed to mobile view and it displays as it should. Its just on the phone and tablet, like the physical phone and tablet where it doesn't show. I am totally confused. The container is properly loaded with data. What am I missing...